# nodejs nested forEach, aggregating results

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, loopbackjs

I'm very new to nodejs's async.forEach and I'm having trouble aggregating the result of my nested forEach loop.

I have a dynamic range of dates and a number of screens that I would like to loop through and either create a schedule or update an existing one.  That part works as designed.  However, I can't get construct an array of all schedules that has been created and have been updated.  I seem to only get the first one but not the rest.

I've tried many different ways of calling the callback but the most I've ever gotten is just one item in my output array.

I've tried different methods from this website but I haven't gotten the luck:
http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice

What is the best way of handling this scenario?

Below is my trimmed down loopback remoteMethod:

===========================

```
Schedule.Reservation = function(PostData, cb) {
  var output = []; // <-- I would like to return this array ... which is report of all created and updated schedules
  try {
    // create all models
    async.series([
          function validateData(callback) {
            callback();
          },
          function processReservation(callback) {
            var screens = PostData.Screens;
            var dates = getDateRangeArray(PostData);

            async.forEach(dates, function(liveDate, callbackDate)
                //for (var d = new Date(PostData.StartDate); d <= end; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) 
                {
                  async.forEach(screens, function(screen, callbackScreen)
                      //for (var s=0;s<screens.length;s++)
                      {
                        if (screen.details)

                          async.forEach(screen.details.BookingInformation, function(frame, callbackFrame) {
                              if ((frame.BlockedDays == 0) || (!isBlocked)) {
                                Schedule.findOne({
                                    where: {
                                      LiveDate: liveDate,
                                      ScreenID: screen.id,
                                      FrameID: frame.FrameID,
                                      Remaining: {
                                        gte: PostData.RequiredSlots
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }, function(errSchedule, schedule) {
                                    var scheduleLog = {}
                                    scheduleLog.liveDate = liveDate;
                                    scheduleLog.ScreenID = screen.id;
                                    scheduleLog.FrameID = frame.FrameID;

                                    if (!errSchedule) {
                                      if (!schedule) {
                                        var tempSchedule = {
                                          LiveDate: liveDate,
                                          Posts: "posts",
                                          Remaining: remain
                                        }
                                        Schedule.create(tempSchedule,
                                          function(err, result) {
                                            if (err) {
                                              output.push({
                                                'Failed': scheduleLog,
                                                'Error': err
                                              });
                                              //callbackFrame(output);
                                            } else {
                                              output.push({
                                                'Created': scheduleLog,
                                                'Success': result
                                              });
                                              //callbackFrame(output);
                                            }
                                          });
                                      } else {
                                        schedule.Remaining--;
                                        schedule.save(function(err, result) {
                                          if (err) {
                                            output.push({
                                              'Failed': scheduleLog,
                                              'Error': err
                                            });
                                            //callbackFrame(output);                                                    
                                          } else {
                                            output.push({
                                              'Updated': scheduleLog,
                                              'Success': result
                                            });
                                            //callbackFrame(output);
                                          }
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        output.push({
                                          'Skipped': scheduleLog,
                                          'Warning': 'Warning: Unable to update. Validation failed. ' + schedule
                                        });
                                        //callbackFrame(output);
                                      }
                                    }
                                  } else {
                                    output.push({
                                      'Skipped': scheduleLog,
                                      'Error': errSchedule
                                    });
                                    //callbackFrame(output);                                                
                                  }
                                }
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          function(result) {
                            if (output)
                              callback(output);
                            else
                              callbackScreen();
                          });
                      else {
                        throw new Error("Invalid Data");
                        return callbackScreen(output); //should throw an error.
                      }
                    },
                    function(result) {
                      if (output)
                        callbackDate(output);
                      else
                        callbackDate(output);
                    });
              },
              function(result) {
                if (output)
                  callback(output);
                else
                  callback();
              });
          //callback(output);
        }
      ],
      function(result) {
        if (output) //also tried result, the outcome is the same.
        {
          cb(null, output);
        } else
          cb("Failed!!!");
      });
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex.message);
  cb('!Error! ' + ex.message);
}
```

Comment: The level of nesting is impressive, it's probably time to break this code down to functions. This leads to some errors like `if (!schedule)` having 2 `else` clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use caolin's async library? See this link to get an idea on how to proceed: https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback

Do not enclose your async code inside a `try-catch` as the `async series/forEach` provide their own way to handle any error. Typically any async callback accepts 2 parameters: `error`, `result`.

`callbackScreen` or `callbackDate` must call `callback` (second handler) to pass some result over in order to hook up your final series' callback (the one you declare at the same level of `async.series`).

```
async.series([
    function A(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'abc'); //first arg is err. If not null you'll go to the final handler below
    },
    function B(callback){
         // do some more stuff ...
         async.forEach(dates, function(liveDate, callbackDate) {
          //stuff to do with dates
          callbackDate(null, 'your data'); //will go to the handler right below
         }, function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.error(err.message);
           //here call callback of function B
           callback(null, data'); //first arg is err
         }))

    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['abc', 'your data']
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I read between your lines and the biggest learning curve I surmounted on this one is the concept behind the callback parameters and which one should be called and where. Thank you!